# How do I SELECT these two tables using single PDO query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have two tables, which I want to SELECT using a single PDO query and positional placeholders.

I've been going through similar questions here to find a solution, but none seems to match the issues I'm having.

The following code is the section of my script:

```
// query users table to retrieve its contents   
if (isset($_SESSION["user_id"]["0"])) {
    // select a particular user by user_id
    $user_id = isset($_POST["user_id"]) ? $_POST["user_id"] : '';

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id=?", $_SESSION["user_id"]["0"]);
    $stmt->execute([$user_id]);
    $user = $stmt->fetch(); # get user data
}

// query courses table to retrieve its contents            
$cid = $_POST["cid"] ?? NULL;
if (is_null($cid)) {
    $stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM courses");
} else {
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM courses WHERE cid = ?");
    $stmt->execute([$cid]);
}

$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo '<option value="">' . "Select a course to proceed" . '</option>';
foreach ($results as $row) {
    echo '<option value=" ' . $row["cid"] . ' ">' . $row["c_name"] . '</option>';
}
```

Apart from echoing `$row["cid"]` (course ID) and `$row["c_name"]` (course name) from the courses table, I'm also echoing the following from the same courses table: `$row["code"]`, `$row["duration"`], `$row["start"]`

In the users table, I have the logged in user's `"user_id"`, `"firstname"`, `"lastname"`, `"username"`, `"email"`, which I also want to include in the above foreach loop. That means the user must be logged in.

Comment: What are these two tables? Your code contains three statements. Are these tables connected in any way such that using a `JOIN` makes sense?

Comment: @NicoHaase, Thanks for your time. The connection of the two tables is that on that very script - course registration, I want to populate form fields from both the users and courses tables. That would enable me to insert a user's registered course.

Comment: You need another table that relates the two tables to indicate which courses the user is registered in. `user_courses` would have two foreign keys, `user_id` and `course_id`.

Comment: You would then use a `JOIN` between all 3 tables.

Comment: @Barmar, Thanks for your input. I already have a third table called `course_registration` and in it I have `user_id` and `cid` (`course_id`). I'm trying to populate form fields from both the `users` and `courses` tables to be inserted into `course_registration`.

Comment: Why would you need to put the user information in the `foreach` loop? It doesn't need to be part of the `<option>` element. It should be displayed once on the page, and doesn't need to be in the form. When the form is submitted you can use the session variable to put the user ID in the inserted rows.

Comment: Why do you have a second argument to `prepare()`? The value of the parameter is in the `execute()` call.

Comment: And if the session variable is set to the logged in user, why are you using `$_POST['user_id']`?

Comment: @Barmar, a million thanks. I now understand why user information is not supposed to be in the `foreach` loop. How can I use session variable to put the user ID into the inserted row? I have removed `$_POST['user_id']` from the script, since the user is logged in.

Comment: The user ID is in `$_SESSION['user_id'][0]`, so use that when inserting.

Comment: I wonder why `$_SESSION['user_id']` is an array instead of a single variable, but that's a separate issue.

Comment: @Barmar, may you tell me the better approach to writing `$_SESSION['user_id']`?

Comment: It should just be a single variable, not an array.

Comment: @Barmar, can you please can you guide me how to change that to a variable? This is what I have in functions.php file: 
 
 `/*
 Check if the admin is logged in or not
    */
   function studentLogin()
   {
     
     $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?");
        $stmt->execute([$username]);
        $user = $stmt->fetch(); # get user data
  
     if ($_SESSION["user_id"] !== $user)
  {
      header('Location: login.php');
      exit;
     }
   }`

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT p. p_id, p.cus_id, p.p_name, c1.name1, c2.name2  

FROM product AS p  

LEFT JOIN customer1 AS c1  

ON p.cus_id=c1.cus_id  

LEFT JOIN customer2 AS c2  

ON p.cus_id = c2.cus_id
```

You can achieve this by doing this. There are 2-3 ways more but this is simplest.

Comment: Why would a `product` table have a customer ID field in it?

Comment: I'm not SELECTING three tables, because `course_registration` is currently empty.

Comment: What I meant to ask is this: Is it proper to SELECT three tables, when the `course_registration` table is currently empty and is the table that needs to be populated?